# Program syntax error in python 3.3.2?

Tags: python, syntax, python-3.x

Syntax error in python 3.3.2:

What is my problem?

```
number=13

i= int(input("enter a number==>"))

if i>number :

   print('big')

   else:

   print('little')
```

Comment: Indentation of `else:` is.

Answer (score 2):

```
number=13

i= int(input("enter a number==>"))

if i>number :

   print('big')

else:

   print('little')
```

You added a tab just before else.